# menu not getting visible outside fixed area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Check [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/r9j3psgk/), due to some space constraints red-area is fixed, and inside that I have some bootstrap dropdown-menu(which is having submenus as well.)

I have given `overflow:hidden;` to `#fixedwidtharea` which is required. (Please don't suggest to remove this  property, I can't.)

According to requirement, Red-area will be fixed always, menus will generate dynamically,  but main problem is submenus are cutting. Is there any work around by we can make submenus visible.

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixedwidtharea">
<ul class="nav nav-pills biggerwidth">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Regular link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1">
            <li> <a href="#">2-level Menu <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="nav-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">Menu</a>

    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">Menu</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}
#fixedwidtharea {
    background:red;
    width:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#biggerwidth {
    width:800px !important;
}
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

Comment: maybe bootply tutorial helps you: http://www.bootply.com/86684

Comment: if you add container div ...are you able to edit this: `dropdown` class? If you can, please note this is more of the manual way.

Comment: can you please update in fiddle? it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS pseudo element `before` and `after` and use `overflow: hidden;` inside those elements to **preserve the layout**. Like so -

```
#fixedwidtharea:before,
#fixedwidtharea:after{
    content: "";    
    display: block;    
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

And then remove `overflow: hidden;` from `#fixedwidtharea`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/r9j3psgk/7/)**

**EDIT:** If you are unable to remove the `overflow: hidden;` from `#fixedwidtharea` then you can explicitly declare the `overflow` to be visible.

```
#fixedwidtharea {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: hmm this is actually pretty good. Though he specifically says he cant touch the overflow from that id. If he can...As long as you dont use ie9 or less this is your answer

Comment: What is the issue with IE9?

Comment: Well I meant below it

Comment: You said **ie9 or less** in your comment. Anyway, what is the issue?

Comment: below ies wont take pseudo calls

Comment: IE8 supports the single-colon CSS 2.1 syntax (i.e. :pseudo-class) Check here- http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent

Comment: hmm well good i thought `after` was not even understood by ie8

Comment: @anis didn't got "explicitly declare" ? can you please elaborate more.. or update the fiddle with explicit declaration.

Comment: @anis as i mentioned in que menus will come dynamically, so if i go with explicit declaration, there may be more menus they will be shown outside red area as well check this http://jsfiddle.net/r9j3psgk/8/

Comment: @ankit You are using a fixed height (`height:70px;`) in `#fixedwidtharea` that's why menu are getting outside the red area.

Comment: @anis it's "fixedarea", as per requirement height and width will be fixed.

Comment: @ankit You cannot expect more items in a fixed area where the room is too short. You already have the solution of your main question. Please don't comment more here. If you still have more discussion you can move this conversation to a chat.

Answer (score 0):

can you modify CSS to have

```
#fixedwidtharea {overflow: visible;}
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` can't be overridden by descendent elements. Can you add container div?

Comment: This is why I added in the comments and not an answer..... Anyways that is why I asked the follow up if he can add container div...sheesh but i see your point should had added on OP

Comment: @Riskbreaker can you please add container and update the fiddle, I am okay with adding container div.

Answer (score 0):

Use Clear-fix trick instead of overflow (I guess this should work on IE<8 also)

Add this class to the fixed width div :

```
<div id="fixedwidtharea" class="clearfix">...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";    
    display: block;    
    height: 0;    
    overflow: hidden; 
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

and remove the overflow:hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/0kmpbj6c/